# How to create meetings on Outlook without it saving in your calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

How do you create a meeting in outlook without it going into your calendar when your just doing it on behalf of someone else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are arranging a meeting on someone elses behalf, you should arrange to be able to raise meetings in their calendar rather than your own.

The person should share their calendar with "Create Items" permissions. They can right-click on their calendar and choose "Properties", then go to the Permissions tab. They should add you and choose the appropriate permissions.

Once done, you will be able to open their calendar and create new meetings. Meeting invites will go out from your email but will be marked "on behalf of ....". The meeting will only show up in the other persons calendar unless you include yourself as an attendee.